# Sharing runtime assembly in C# Roslyn script

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, roslyn, csx

I have maybe a bit of a unique setup here. I am hosting am embedded .net runtime in a c++ app  using `nethost.h` and loading my assembly and getting fn pointers with `load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer`. It's invoking everything fine. In the function I'm calling on the .net side I am using Roslyn to run .csx scripts.

In that .net lib I define an interface `INpcEvent` and in the .csx I create a class that implements that interface and returns a new instance. I want to be able to get a reference to that new instance via this code:

```cs
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile($"{directory}/DotNetTypes.dll")); // This is already referenced in this running assembly as a dependency
var state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync<GlobalType.INpcEvent>(text, scriptOptions, globals: global, globalsType: typeof(GlobalType));
```

And I get the error Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'`

I did some debugging and found that there were two separate assemblies loaded, although they are both pointing to the same assembly on disk (DotNetType.dll).

I was able to get things "working" by defining factory methods with serializable types to create the arguments I needed like the following

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile($"{directory}/DotNetTypes.dll"));
    var state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync<object>(text, scriptOptions);
    NpcMap[npcName] = state.ReturnValue;
    var instance = NpcMap[npcName];
    var createNpcEvent = instance.GetType()?.BaseType?.Assembly.ExportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FullName == "EqFactory")?.GetMethod("CreateNpcEvent");
    if (createNpcEvent != null)
    {
        var npcEvent = createNpcEvent.Invoke(instance, [initArgs?.Zone, initArgs?.EntityList, npcEventArgs.Npc, npcEventArgs.Mob, message ?? ""]);
        var methodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethod(MethodMap[id]);
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            methodInfo.Invoke(instance, [npcEvent]);
        }
    }
```

But I'd really like to be able to reuse the same assembly in runtime. Is there something I'm missing or another alternative to Roslyn to be able to achieve this?

Comment: Update, the solution turned out to be using a different method `Create` rather than `RunAsync`:

                var loader = new InteractiveAssemblyLoader();
                loader.RegisterDependency(assembly);
                loader.RegisterDependency(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assembly.Location)).WithReferences(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                var state = await CSharpScript.Create<INpcEvent>(text, scriptOptions, assemblyLoader: loader).RunAsync();